# How much does Antivenom cost in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pricing

[Antivenom](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Antivenom) is a very potent substance very much worth carrying around if you think that a possibility of encountering a certain monster is real and can get your hands on a vial or two. For example, I'd like my character to have Antivenom against Phase Spiders.

Creating this item is a complex process that requires a dose of target venom. However, prices are only listed for a very limited set of poisons. I think I remember seeing a formula based on monster CR, but I didn't happen to find it now, and it might actually be a figment of my imagination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your own link,

> #### Purchasing Antivenom
>
> Antivenom is not particularly expensive, but because it is highly specialized, it can be difficult to find. **A dose of antivenom has a market price equal to half the market price of a dose of the poison in question**, but it is treated as though its price were five times the market price of the poison for the purposes of determining its availability in any given settlement. **Alternatively, if 1 or more doses of the poison in question can be provided, most alchemists will supply as much antivenom as they can produce from the doses for a fee of 10% of the market price of the poison.**

<sup>([Antivenom description](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Antivenom), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

So it costs half the given poison does, or a tenth if you already have the poison. Mundane crafting costs one-third the purchase price, so a sixth or a thirtieth if you already have the poison.

The cost of the poison itself, however, is going to be up to the GM in a large number of cases, because there are not any rules for determining it. I do not believe there is any CR-based formula as you recall; I have never heard of such a thing and the closest I could find was a homebrew effort.

Comment: To be more specific, I don't understand how to determine the poison price. There are prices listed for some poisons, but not, say, Phase Spider poison.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy because maybe such poisons can't be bought, you'd need to harvest them from the spider

Comment: @Trish Then this is the answer -- it can't be bought.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy No, that’s an answer to a *separate question* that you *didn’t originally ask*, and instead have morphed this one into after the fact. Please be more careful with your questions.

Comment: @KRyan I will try to. Sorry.